# Why does Xcode Playground execute liveView through iPad-like Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, swift-playground

[image]

I'm trying some codes in Xcode 8.2.1 Playground with Swift 3.
I've been confused since `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` executes iPad-like simulator.
I want to test keyboard input through a simulator of smaller device. Can I handle this better?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTextView()
    }

    private func setupTextView() {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        textView.backgroundColor = .gray
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.font = textView.font?.withSize(20)
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }

}

let viewController = ViewController()
let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 600))
window.rootViewController = viewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = window
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: can you also paste the code instead of a picture? Im not gonna type all this :/

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift added! :pray:

Comment: Still the same issue with xcode 9.1-2

Comment: Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867712/swift-playground-uitextfield-spawns-keyboard-that-is-too-big

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift playground UITextField spawns keyboard that is too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867712/swift-playground-uitextfield-spawns-keyboard-that-is-too-big)

Comment: +1 this question because I've wondered the same thing, and spent a decent amount of time googling and reading docs, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
let viewController = ViewController()
let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 600))
window.rootViewController = viewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = window
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Try this

```
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 600)

import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

This is how I change the size of my view controllers in Playgrounds

Answer (score -1):

It might be related to the "[Swift Playgrounds](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id908519492?mt=8)" app?

The app is iPad-only (You can't even find it in App Store on iPhone).